# Why does $y \downarrow x$ imply $ x \leftrightarrow^* y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science, relations, rewriting-systems

In [Baader's *Term rewriting and all that*](https://books.google.com/books?id=i37uBgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT24&dq=Term%20rewriting%20and%20all%20that%3A%20Definition%202.1.3&pg=PT24#v=onepage&q=Term%20rewriting%20and%20all%20that:%20Definition%202.1.3&f=false):

> Definition 2.1.3 A reduction $\rightarrow$ is called
> Church-Rosserf iff  $ x \leftrightarrow^* y \Rightarrow y \downarrow x$
>
> Because $y \downarrow x$ implies $ x \leftrightarrow^* y$, the Church-Rosser property can also be
> phrased as an equivalence: $x \leftrightarrow^* y \Leftrightarrow x \downarrow y$.

Why does  $y \downarrow x$ imply $ x \leftrightarrow^* y$? (In other words, why if y and x have a common successor, then they are equivalent?)

For the definitions, also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting#Normal_forms,_joinability_and_the_word_problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of symmetric closure, $\ \leftrightarrow\ :=\ \rightarrow \cup \leftarrow\ =\ \rightarrow \cup \ (\rightarrow)^{-1}\ $, means that two objects satisfy this relation if either $x \rightarrow y$ or $y \rightarrow x$. Hence $x \leftrightarrow^* y$ can be interpreted as "either $x=y$ or there exists a path, *regardless of arrow direction*, connecting $x$ and $y$."

The implication $\exists z(x \rightarrow^* z \leftarrow^* y) \Rightarrow x \leftrightarrow^* y$ should now make sense intuitively.